# How to add queryset to ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I have following models:

```
class EnMovielist(models.Model):
    content_ID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    running_time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    actress = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    studio = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content_ID


class EnActress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    movielist = models.ManyToManyField(EnMovielist, related_name='movies')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I got error when I try to this in Django shell,

```
b = EnActress.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
a = EnMovielist.objects.filter(actress__contains=b).values_list('content_ID')

b.movielist.add(a)



AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'movielist'
```

How can I django queryset add into many-to-many field?
I have no idea why this is happening.. Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: If you still need to work with querysets then you shouldn't be using `values_list`, the code you've shown doesn't make much sense and I'm not sure what its trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using `values_list` if you intend to `add` a new relation afterwards. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

> `values()` and `values_list()` are both intended as optimizations for
>   a specific use case: retrieving a subset of data **without the
>   overhead of creating a model instance**

[*Emphasis mine*]

It's hard to tell what you're up to without having a good description of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should call m2m `add` from instance and adding entity should be also model instance. Otherwise your expression doesn't make sense.

```
b = EnActress.objects.get(pk=some_pk) # get an instance, not queryset
a = EnMovielist.objects.get(pk=some_pk) # also instance
b.movielist.add(a)
```